# Как вставить Spring Bean в xml для factory

Tags: java, xml, spring, java-ee

Без Spring я инициализировал объект так:

```
DAOFactory factory = new MySqlDaoFactory
StudentDao studentDao = factory.getStudentDAO(connection)
```

Как мне это правильно прописать в bean, передать на вход методу getStudentDAO connection ?
Я писал так, но выскакивает ошибка:

```
 <bean id="MySqlDaoFactory" class="mysql.MySqlDaoFactory">
    </bean>
     <bean id="DaoFactory" class="dao.DaoFactory">
    </bean>
    <bean id="Connection" class="mysql.MySqlDaoFactory"
    factory-bean="MySqlDaoFactory" factory-method="getConnection">
    </bean>
    <bean id="studentDao" class="mysql.MySqlStudentDao"
    factory-bean="MySqlDaoFactory" factory-method="getStudentDAO" constructor-arg="Connection">
    </bean>
```

класс DAOFactory и StudentDao абстрактные

класс MySqlDaoFactory:

```
public class MySqlDaoFactory extends DAOFactory{
    private Connection connection = null;
    public Connection getConnection() throws DAOException {
        Properties prop = new Properties();
        try {
           ...
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new DAOException("Error of connection", e);
        }
        return connection;
    }
     public StudentDao getStudentDAO(Connection connection){
        return new MySqlStudentDao(connection);
    }
```

MysqlStudentDao наследует абстрактный StudentDao и прописывает все CRUD

Comment: constructor-arg  ref="Connection"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

вам нужно ссылать на существующий бин Connection, поэтому указываете ссылку на него через `constructor-arg ref=`

В вашем случае будет

```
<bean id="studentDao" class="mysql.MySqlStudentDao"
    factory-bean="MySqlDaoFactory" factory-method="getStudentDAO" constructor-arg ref="Connection">
</bean>
```